# How should I setup Mailhog to work with Docksal?

Tags: php, email, docksal

I have follow official documentation on https://docs.docksal.io/tools/mailhog/
But can not get mails on mailhog. 
In logs (fin logs -f cli) I have:

*WARNING: [pool www] child 49 said into stderr: "sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/mhsendmail: not found"*

**My docksal.yml:**

```
version: "2.1"
services:
mail:
  extends:
    file: ${HOME}/.docksal/stacks/services.yml
    service: mail
```

**My script (test.php):**

```
var_dump(mail('ds@test.com', 'test', 'test', 'From: d@test.com' . "\r\n", '-f d@test.com'));
```

always returns bool(false) and no mails in the mailhog dashboard.
What could be wrong?

Comment: We have a blog post for [using mailhog and swiftmailer on Docksal](https://blog.docksal.io/mailhog-and-swiftmailer-in-local-development-102ce0c2a631).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error is a line

```
sendmail_path = '/usr/local/bin/mhsendmail --smtp-addr=mail:1025'
```

in project/.docksal/etc/php/php.ini

Need to delete it and everything is OK.

PS.
Seems it comes from

```
fin addon install mailhog
```

command.